# Can you add UIViewRepresentable (UISearchBar) as a navigationBarItem? - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am setting the `leading` and `trailing` `navigationBarItems` like this

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: SearchBar(text: $searchText), trailing: rightTopBarItems())
```

The `trailing` items show up fine but `SearchBar` does not appear. Is it possible to add a `UIViewRepresentable` as a `navigationBarItem`? I cannot find anything in the documentation.

SearchBar code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var text: String

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @Binding var text: String

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
      _text = text
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      text = searchText
    }
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $text)
  }

  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
    searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.minimal
    return searchBar
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
    uiView.text = text
  }
}
```

Comment: By my findings it works properly, now, only within `VStack` under `List`

Comment: Do you mean I should try VStack { List { SearchBar(text: $searchText) } }? That did not make any difference.

Comment: No, I used `VStack { SearchBar(text: $searchText) List {  } }`

Comment: This wouldn't compile because List has to return some thing. I changed that to VStack { SearchBar(text: $searchText) List { EmptyView() } } but this still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
So, I gave up adding `UIViewRepresentable` and decided to use`TextField` directly.

I hope this serves your purpose.

```
struct SearchTextField: View {
    @State var input: String = ""
    @Binding var searchText: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            TextField("Search word", text: $input, onCommit: {
                self.searchText = self.input
            })
        }
    }
}

final class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var searchText = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SearchViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                HStack {
                    SearchTextField(searchText: $viewModel.searchText)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this solution has some drawbacks, the most noticeable being that you can't commit changes directly with each letter: if you do something like `Text("\(self.input)")` or if you have a `List` that gets filtered based on $input, the iOS keyboard closes after every new letter. I guess this happens because SwiftUI updates the view and decides to close the keyboard at the same time. I haven't found a workaround yet.